# Pointers to the same object Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, pointers, object, nsstring, nsmutablestring

I have the following code. When I print out aString it is Goodbye and when i print out bString it is Hellworld. Shouldn't bString be pointing to the same object as aString. I would expect both to print Goodbye. Also when i print out the memory addresses of the pointers they are different memeory addresses. Can someone explain why?

```
NSString *aString = @"Helloworld";
NSString *bString = aString;

aString = @"Goodbye";
```

I want bString to point to the same object as aString. So if the value of aString changes then the value of bString also changes and vice-versa. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why do you expect bString to have the latest value of Astring ? aString is not a method to return it's latest value.

Comment: I want bString to point to the same object as aString. When I write NSString *bString = aString; shouldn't bString point to the same object in memory?

Comment: It does in that moment.

Comment: Pointers are no different than other types in this behavior. Try the same experiment with some `int`s: `int i = 10; j = i; i = 8;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a visualisation of what's happening in your code, line by line.

```
aString –––––––––> @"Helloworld"
```

```
aString –––––––––> @"Helloworld"
                        ^
                        |
bString –––––––––––––––––
```

```
aString –––––––––> @"Goodbye"   @"Helloworld"
                                     ^
                                     |
bString ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
```

As you can see, pointing `aString` to another object has no effect on the object that `bString` is already pointing to. You simply end up with two pointers each pointing to different objects.

In order to achieve your desired behaviour of having `aString` and `bString` pointing to the same object, which you need to be able to change, you're going to need a *mutable* object (such as `NSMutableString`, as Franklin says).

This will allow you to mutate the underlying object, rather than creating and pointing to a new object – therefore `aString` and `bString` will stay pointed to the same object after the mutation, allowing them both to observe the same value.

The mutation would simply look like this:

```
aString –––––––––> @"Helloworld"
                        ^
                        |
bString –––––––––––––––––
```

```
aString –––––––––>  @"Goodbye"
                        ^
                        |
bString –––––––––––––––––
```

Comment: Do I need to use KVO to get bString changed based upon aString ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri If `aString` is a property, then yes you could indeed use KVO in order to observe when its value changes – or simply override its setter if you're doing this from within the class itself.

Comment: Good graph buddy. Easier to understand than address stuff.

Answer (score 3):

After

```
NSString *aString = @"Helloworld";
```

in memory `0x01` (or somewhere) there is a string `@"Helloworld"`; then the address `0x01` is assigned to `aString`. After

```
NSString *bString = aString;
```

the address `0x01` is assigned to `bString`. Warning! After

```
aString = @"Goodbye";
```

the address `0x01` is *still* `@"Helloworld"`! This line *does not* alter the string. It creates a new string `@"Goodbye"` and store it at `0x46` (or somewhere other than `0x01`), and assign the address `0x46` to `aString`. To do what you want, try [`NSMutableString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/index.html).

Note: do not create new `NSMutableString`s; modify the current one with

```
- (void)setString:(NSString *)aString
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Whenever you're creating a string using the `@""` syntax, the framework will automatically cache the string. `NSString` is a very special class, but the framework will take care of it. When you use `@"Some String"` in multiple places of your app, they will all point to the same address in memory. Only when you're using something like `-initWithData:encoding`, the string won't be cached.

2) The other answers suggested that you should use `-copy` instead, but `-copy` will only create immutable copies if the receiver is mutable. (Like `NSMutableString`)
When you're sending `-copy` to an immutable object, it'll be the same as `-retain`.

```
NSString *originalString = @"Some String";
NSString *copy = [originalString copy];
NSString *mutableCopy = [originalString mutableCopy];
NSString *mutableCopyCopy = [mutableCopy copy];
NSString *anotherString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:originalString];
```

originalString, copy, mutableCopyCopy and anotherString will all point to the same memory address, only mutableCopy points do a different region of memory.

Comment: By "framework" you mean "compiler" and by "cached" you are referring to [string interning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning).